# Is there a correct way to do this layout in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development and I am making a small "About Me" website using html/css .
I managed to do this layout : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyCU0.jpg

Although it did the job done, I am just concerned that with this layout/code will affect the future ones

```css
.container {
    transform: translate( 0, 150px);
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100vh;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

.pfp {
    width: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 60px;
}

.pfpp {
    width : 250px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.textt {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;

}

.txtdesign {
    color: white;
    transform: translate(250px, 150px);
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<section id="AboutMe">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="pfp">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?text=my%20face" class="pfpp">
            </div> 
            <div class="textt">   
            <h1 class="txtdesign">Hi! My name is...</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do something like this:**

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

.item1{grid-area:pfp;}
.item2{grid-area:text;}

.container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px auto;
  width:80%;
  background-color:black;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:10vh;
  padding:30px 30px 30px 30px;
  height:90%;
  border-radius:10px;
  min-height:600px;
}
```

```html
<section id="AboutMe">

    <div class="container">
    
        <div class="pfp">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?text=my%20face">
        </div> 
        
        <div class="text" style="padding:5px 20px 5px 20px;">   
          <h1 class="txtdesign" style="color:white">Hi! My name is...</h1>
        </div>
        
    </div>

</section>
```

**Note:** this css uses grid layout, you can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much its much better now :D

Comment: I apologize I cannot upvote this answer because my reputation is too low, but thank you so much

Comment: There are cool features in CSS that allow you to do complex things with simple code. It's good to learn different approaches, because CSS codes can become really dirty and unpleasant.